# Fitting arbitrary gaussian functions, massive memory consumption in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to (in python) fit a series of an arbitrary number of gaussian functions (determined by a simple algorithm still being improved) to a data set. For my current sample data set, I have 174 gaussian functions. I have a procedure for doing the fit, but it's basically complicated guess-and-check, and consumes all 4GB of memory available.

Is there any way to accomplish this using something in scipy or numpy?

Here is what I'm trying to use, where wavelength[] is the list of x-coordinates, and fluxc[] is the list of y-coordinates:

```
#Pick a gaussian
for repeat in range(0,2):
    for f in range(0,len(centroid)):
        #Iterate over every other gaussian
        for i in range(0,len(centroid)):
            if i!= f:
                #For every wavelength,
                for w in wavelength:
                    #Append the value of each to an list, called others
                    others.append(height[i]*math.exp(-(w-centroid[i])**2/(2*width[i]**2)))

    #Optimize the centroid of the current gaussian
        prev = centroid[f]
        best = centroid[f]
        #Pick an order of magnitude
        for p in range (int(round(math.log10(centroid[i]))-3-repeat),int(round(math.log10(centroid[i])))-6-repeat,-1):
            #Pick a value of that order of magnitude
            for m in range (-5,9):
                #Change the value of the current item
                centroid[f] = prev + m * 10 **(p)
                #Increment over all wavelengths, make a list of the new values
                variancy = 0
                residual = 0
                test = []
                #Increment across every wavelength and evaluate if this change gets R^2 any larger
                for k in range(0,len(wavelength)):
                    test.append(height[i]*math.exp(-(wavelength[k]-centroid[f])**2/(2*width[i]**2)))
                    residual += (test[k]+others[k]-cflux[k])**2
                    variancy += (test[k]+others[k]-avgcflux)**2
                rsquare = 1-(residual/variancy)
                #Check the R^2 value for this new fit
                if rsquare > bestr:
                    bestr = rsquare
                    best = centroid[f]
        centroid[f] = best

    #Optimize the height of the current gaussian
        prev = height[f]
        best = height[f]
        #Pick an order of magnitude
        for p in range (int(round(math.log10(height[i]))-repeat),int(round(math.log10(height[i])))-3-repeat,-1):
            #Pick a value of that order of magnitude
            for m in range (-5,9):
                #Change the value of the current item
                height[f] = prev + m * 10 **(p)
                #Increment over all wavelengths, make a list of the new values
                variancy = 0
                residual = 0
                test = []
                #Increment across every wavelength and evaluate if this change gets R^2 any larger
                for k in range(0,len(wavelength)):
                    test.append(height[f]*math.exp(-(wavelength[k]-centroid[i])**2/(2*width[i]**2)))
                    residual += (test[k]+others[k]-cflux[k])**2
                    variancy += (test[k]+others[k]-avgcflux)**2
                rsquare = 1-(residual/variancy)
                #Check the R^2 value for this new fit
                if rsquare > bestr:
                    bestr = rsquare
                    best = height[f]
        height[f] = best

    #Optimize the width of the current gaussian
        prev = width[f]
        best = width[f]
        #Pick an order of magnitude
        for p in range (int(round(math.log10(width[i]))-repeat),int(round(math.log10(width[i])))-3-repeat,-1):
            #Pick a value of that order of magnitude
            for m in range (-5,9):
                if prev + m * 10**(p) == 0:
                    m+=1
                #Change the value of the current item
                width[f] = prev + m * 10 **(p)
                #Increment over all wavelengths, make a list of the new values
                variancy = 0
                residual = 0
                test = []
                #Increment across every wavelength and evaluate if this change gets R^2 any larger
                for k in range(0,len(wavelength)):
                    test.append(height[i]*math.exp(-(wavelength[k]-centroid[i])**2/(2*width[f]**2)))
                    residual += (test[k]+others[k]-cflux[k])**2
                    variancy += (test[k]+others[k]-avgcflux)**2
                rsquare = 1-(residual/variancy)
                #Check the R^2 value for this new fit
                if rsquare > bestr:
                    bestr = rsquare
                    best = width[f]
        width[f] = best
        count += 1
        #print '{} of {} peaks optimized, iteration {} of {}'.format(f+1,len(centroid),repeat+1,2)
        complete = round(100*(count/(float(len(centroid))*2)),2)
        print '{}% completed'.format(complete)
    print 'New R^2 = {}'.format(bestr)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can likely be done better (easier) using scipy. But firstly, refactor your code into smaller functions; it justs makes it a lot easier to read and understand what's going on.

As for the memory consumption: you're probably overextending a list far too much somewhere (`others` is a candidate: I never see it cleared (or initialized!), while it gets filled in a quadruple loop). That, or your data is simply that large (in which case you really should be using numpy arrays, just to speed up things). I can't tell, because you're introducing various variables without giving any idea of the size (how big is `wavelengths`? How large does `others` get? What and where are all the initializations of your data arrays?)

Also, fitting 174 Gaussians is just a bit crazy; either look into another way of determining whatever you want to get out of your data, or split things up. From the `wavelengths` variable, it appears you're trying to fit lines in a high resolution spectrum; perhaps isolating most of the lines and fitting those isolated groups separately is better. If they all overlap, I doubt any normal fitting technique is going to help you.

Lastly, perhaps a package like [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) can help (e.g., the [computation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html) subpackage).

Perhaps very lastly, since I see a lot that can be improved in the code. At some point [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) may also be useful. Though for now I guess your memory usage is the most problematic part.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

This is only about a third of all the code I've written, everything is initialized earlier on. It is for analyzing a high-resolution spectra, right now with 992 data points. Is that far too many?

I'd like to try to avoid breaking up the data before analyzing it, so I can extract as much useful data as possible.